# Internet Connection Detector using while loop

Tags: c#, while-loop

I am trying to build a small program that checks for internet connection using while loop, quite new to C#, if possible could you help me figure out the problem with this program thanks.

```
var client = new WebClient();
while (true)
{
     var stream =client.OpenRead("http://www.google.com").ToString();
     Console.Write("You are in");
     Console.ReadLine();
     if (stream == "false")
     {
         Console.WriteLine("You are out");
         break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When you post a question with some code attached, could you also mention what exactly is the error you receive. Post the exception message or describe the behaviour of your come. So, what is the error you get?

Comment: Hi Gnqz, thanks for your replay. The code is working fine. It's just the final "You are out" string fails to output, whenever, I manually disconnect the internet. I figured it out using different method, but still having problem getting this example working. I believe the problem is with the way, I have layout my while loop method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may just send a `Ping` as following:

```
PingReply pingReply = new Ping().Send("http://www.google.com");

if (pingReply != null && pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
{
    // Internet is ok
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is sample code to check the internet connection. May be this will help you.

```
 public static bool CheckInternetConnection()
 {
   try
   {
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        using (var stream = client.OpenRead("http://www.google.com"))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
  }
 catch
 {
    return false;
  }
}
```

From the main call like this:

```
while (true)
 {
 if(CheckInternetConnection()==true){
   Console.Write("You are in");
}
else{
   Console.Write("You are out");
}
```

}